# How to get date from checkbox and div class to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I clicked on checkbox and I want it to be shown next to the div with class that suits the id from checkbox on the array.

I tried to do it with the code but something is not working.

```js
   

 $('button').on('click', function() {
  var array = [];
  array1.push($(this).text());

  $("input:checked").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).val());
    $('#myModalLink').modal('hide');
  });

  $('#oto').each(function() {
    array1.push($(this).text());

  });

  $('#test').text(array);
  $('#test').text(array1);
});
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="20" /></td>
<td>
  <div id="oto">name</div>
</td>
<td>
  <div id="lng">lng</div>
</td>

 <td><input type="checkbox" value="16" /></td>
<td>
 <div id="oto">name1</div>
</td>
<td>
 <div id="lng">lng1</div>
</td>
```

Comment: I've put your code into a Stack Snippet. You can help by [edit]ing your question and the snippet to include everything needed to show the problem run. In this case, adding a `button` element, maybe removing the line about the modal since it doesn't matter. Also, include the result you expect, and what result you're getting. Read [ask] to find more tips on writing a good question.

Comment: Did you mean: how to get *data*?  Checkbox doesn't have a date (nor does your code)

Comment: As above, I think you could do with before/after HTML (especially after).  You also might want to consider a single array of objects rather than 2(or more) arrays